# How can I make a best fit line out of data where each point is weighted more heavily than the previous?

Tags: least-squares, data-analysis

I'm thinking that there should be a linear regression technique that allows me to value recent data more that older data. (Maybe this difference in weight could be configurable through a constant).

Any ideas?

Comment: Good question. Answer here I think: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/205232/how-to-down-weight-older-data-in-time-series-regression